# Forzar la salida stderr a stdout separandolas por un string

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

necesito ejectuar una lista de comandos separados por una unica cadena de texto:

```
ls -l 2>&1 && echo "__UNIQUE_SEPARATOR" && sls -l  2>&1 && echo "__UNIQUE_SEPARATOR" && pwd
```

Para procesarlas y hacer un `split` por dicho separador, pero por alguna razon despues de que un comando falla, los demas comandos ya no se ejecutan ni tampoco se hace print del string separador.

```
maulinux@ubuntu:~$ ls -l 2>&1 && echo "__UNIQUE_SEPARATOR" && sls -l  2>&1 && echo "__UNIQUE_SEPARATOR" && pwd
total 40
-rw-rw-r-- 1 maulinux maulinux   29 Oct  7 20:22 '&1'
drwxr-xr-x 5 maulinux maulinux 4096 Sep 26 15:22  Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 maulinux maulinux 4096 Aug 19 10:54  Documents
drwxr-xr-x 3 maulinux maulinux 4096 Aug 28 12:31  Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 2 maulinux maulinux 4096 Aug 19 10:54  Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 maulinux maulinux 4096 Aug 19 10:54  Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 maulinux maulinux 4096 Aug 19 10:54  Public
drwxr-xr-x 3 maulinux maulinux 4096 Aug 19 10:54  snap
drwxr-xr-x 2 maulinux maulinux 4096 Aug 19 10:54  Templates
drwxr-xr-x 2 maulinux maulinux 4096 Aug 19 10:54  Videos
__UNIQUE_SEPARATOR

Command 'sls' not found, but there are 21 similar ones.

maulinux@ubuntu:~$
```

Como puedo solucionar este problema?

Comment: he respondido indicando cómo solucionarlo. Ahora bien, sería bueno saber qué quieres hacer pues lo mismo se puede realizar de otra manera.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando ejecutas `comando1 && comando2` le estás diciendo a la consola que ejecute `comando1` y que, si comando1 se ejecuta correctamente, luego ejecute `comando2`.

Por tanto, si `comando1` falla, entonces `comando2` no se ejecutará.

Si quieres ejecutar todos los comandos, independientemente de qué resultado tenga cada uno, usa `;` para cada uno:

```
comando1; comando2
```

De este modo, cada instrucción es independiente de las otras.

Esto, o di `ls` en lugar de `sls`.